# Next.js 13 - How to connect my Transaction Data to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next.js13, nextui

I'm creating a Finance Tracker APP using Next.js, Zod, React Hook Form, and styling with Tailwind/NextUI/shadcn.UI.

My app already has authentication, now I'm trying to push the 'Income/Expense' data to my MongoDB. But it doesn't seems to be working. It doesn't even appears in my 'collections'.

My Form is inside a Modal:

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  ModalContent,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter,
  Button,
  useDisclosure,
  Checkbox,
  Input,
  Link,
} from "@nextui-org/react";
import { Select, SelectItem } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { typesOfTransactions } from "@/lib/types";
import * as z from "zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { TransactionValidation } from "@/lib/validations/transaction";
import { createTransaction } from "@/lib/actions/transaction.actions";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function TransactionModalForm({ userId }: { userId: string }) {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onOpenChange } = useDisclosure();
  const [backdrop, setBackdrop]: any = React.useState("blur");
  const [modalPlacement, setModalPlacement] = React.useState("auto");
  const variants = ["underlined"];
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const handleOpen = (backdrop: any) => {
    setBackdrop(backdrop);
    onOpen();
  };

  const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(TransactionValidation),
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      value: "",
      type: "",
      accountId: userId,
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof TransactionValidation>) => {
    await createTransaction({
      title: values.title,
      description: values.description,
      value: values.value,
      type: values.type,
      author: userId,
      path: pathname,
    });

    router.push("/");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onPress={onOpen}
        className="bg-gradient-to-tl from-pink-500 via-red-500 to-yellow-500 "
      >
        Nova Movimentação
      </Button>
      <Modal
        backdrop={backdrop}
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
        placement="center"
        {...form}
      >
        <ModalContent>
          {(onClose) => (
            <form
              onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="flex flex-col justify-start gap-10 "
            >
              <ModalHeader className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                Nova Transação
              </ModalHeader>
              <ModalBody>
                <Input
                  autoFocus
                  label="Titulo"
                  placeholder="Digite o titulo da movimentação"
                  variant="bordered"
                />
                <Input
                  label="Descrição"
                  placeholder="Digite a descrição da movimentação"
                  variant="bordered"
                />
                <Input
                  label="Valor"
                  placeholder="Digite o valor da movimentação"
                  variant="bordered"
                  type="number"
                />
                <div className="w-full flex flex-col gap-4">
                  {variants.map((variant) => (
                    <div
                      key={variant}
                      className="flex w-full flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap mb-6 md:mb-0 gap-4"
                    >
                      <Select variant={variant as any} label="Selecione o tipo">
                        {typesOfTransactions.map((type) => (
                          <SelectItem key={type.value} value={type.value}>
                            {type.label}
                          </SelectItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
                <Button type="submit">Clicar</Button>
              </ModalBody>
              <ModalFooter>
                <Button color="danger" variant="flat" onPress={onClose}>
                  Fechar
                </Button>
                <Button color="primary" type="submit" onPress={onClose}>
                  Enviar
                </Button>
              </ModalFooter>
            </form>
          )}
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my Zod Validation:

```
import * as z from 'zod';

export const TransactionValidation = z.object({
  title: z.string().url().nonempty(),
  description: z.string().min(3).max(30),
  value: z.string().min(3).max(30),
  type: z.string(),
  accountId: z.string(),
})
```

My Transaction Model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const transactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  value: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const Transaction =
  mongoose.models.Transaction ||
  mongoose.model("Transaction", transactionSchema);

export default Transaction;
```

And my Transaction Actions (Nextjs server actions)

```
"use server";

import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import Transaction from "../models/transaction.model";
import User from "../models/user.model";
import { connectToDB } from "../mongoose";

interface Params {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  value: string;
  type: string;
  author: string;
  path: string;
}

export async function createTransaction({
  title,
  description,
  value,
  type,
  author,
  path,
}: Params) {
  try {
    connectToDB();

    const createdTransaction = await Transaction.create({
      title,
      author,
      description,
      value,
      type,
    });

    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(author, {
      $push: { transactions: createdTransaction._id },
    });

    revalidatePath(path);
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(`Error creating Transaction: ${error}`);
  }
}
```

My guess is: Zod and React Hook Form doesn't seem to work with NextUI Components?

Or is my code logic wrong?
Already searched through the web for solutions, didn't find.

My github repository is:
https://github.com/Claudenir-Nojosa/Trizcla.git

I tried creating the Transaction Schema, reviewed all my transaction actions code, and to me, it seems ok.

I was expecting to push my transaction data to my database.